# Create the first user/password combination in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, admin, keychain

I have a login using *username/password* keychain combinations. And I would like a **"super" user account** who is allowed to add new username/password combinations in the keychain. Every user will use the same device.

I was just wandering how could it be possible to log **for the very first time** since no username/password have been set and since the adding of account is only possible after the first login...

Is there a way to create this super user account from outside the app? Or should I find an other way to create my first super user account from the login page and then remove this option since I have to prevent other people from creating new accounts (like a button that would be removed)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Tricho

Comment: Is there any reason you can't check on launch if there are any accounts added, and if not, programmatically add a 'superuser' that only exists/is accessible until there is a normal user added?

Comment: The fact is that I have not succeeded yet in getting a way to check if a username/password is already present. I don't know how to check if a keychain dictionary returns nil or not. Maybe could you help? Thx!